# How did they know that the Scorpion King comes back every 5000 years?

Tags: the-mummy-returns

In *The Mummy Returns*, the opening scene said that the Scorpion King's soul was taken by Anubis 5000 years ago, and later in the movie, Eve said that the Scorpion King awakens every 5000 years. How would they know he actually awakens every 5000 years if this would've been the first time?

Comment: This reminds me of Brigadoon, where the village of Brigadoon comes to lie for a short time one every hundrd years, and has done so for only 200 years.  But the natives of Brigadoon seem to be familiar with all the clauses of the curse, even though during the story they are only on the third day of their consciousness since the curse started.  How did they learn all the rules of the curse?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the information about the Scorpion King waking up every 5000 years was based on legend or mythology, rather than fact. As Evy being the archeologist should be in possession of this information.

In the movie, it's suggested that the Scorpion King's soul was taken by the god Anubis, which is a part of ancient Egyptian mythology. It's possible that the idea of the Scorpion King waking up every 5000 years was part of this mythology, and was passed down through the centuries. So, even though it would have been the first time the Scorpion King actually awakened in the context of the movie, the characters may have believed it to be true based on the myths and legends they were familiar with.